# How to execute a single instace of my java destop application?

Tags: java, spring, javafx

I'm very new in JavaFX, I did a client-server application. My principal problem is that I only want to execute one single instance by machine.

I'm using SpringFramework, maybe this can help me to to that.

Anybody can help me to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood your question perfectly, so i'll answer and hope to hit the point.

If you want your client part of the application to only have on instance/machine you could:

- check for a file ( create a file when program starts delete when it exists, on start check if it exists do not start if it does )
- bind a predetermined port on localhost

this however wouldn't ensure one instance / machine ( the program could be ran inside a VM ) a proper solution, if you need *exactly* 1 instance/machine, would be implemented server-side, something like ensuring one IP can only have one 'session' with the server.

Hope i grasped what you where looking for.

Edit(reference after comments):
Another option would be:

User A logs in (lets call this connection 1). The server could deny more logins of user A while connection 1 is alive.

Comment: Thanks, I have my server side application, but I don't know how to apply this concept. Because, one option is bind to the IP Address, but what happen if the user change the IP? The user can launch one instance more of the application, and I want to avoid this.

Comment: If your user has to login/authenticate to begin working with the server im guessing the server could only allow one user to have a session at a time, something like, user A authenticates/logs in, server knows that, if another authentication/login process starts for the same user A,while that last connection is live you reject it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use external libraries, give a try to [JUNIQUE](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/junique/).

I have been using it for quite sometime and its great !